# What is the difference between a multiway and a nested if statement in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement

Taking a class in Java, a little confused. What is the difference between a multi-way if statement and a nested if statement?

Comment: Write an example of both, then try to follow the logic when the conditions are met. Do this in a piece of paper.

Comment: I see, so its just the placement of brackets?

Comment: If you're taking a class, that means there's a teacher. Why didn't you ask him/her?

Comment: @brso05: `if (cond) A; else B;` is the same as `if (!cond) B; else A;`; thus one can trivially be converted into the other.  It's just a matter of where the nesting happens, and whether the conditions are inverted.  There's no fundamental difference.

Comment: Technically, @OliverCharlesworth is correct if you look at the syntax of the `if` statement.  `else if` is not part of the syntax; an `else` is succeeded by another statement, that can be a block or another `if`.  It's really just a matter of how we think about it.  There _are_ languages where this is not true (Ada, Perl), where the `if` part of an "else if" part is _not_ just a nested statement, syntactically.

Comment: @brso05: IMO, this is just a semantic argument.  In general, you have `if (x) { if (y) ... else ... } else { if (a) ... else ... }` nested infinitum.   Modelling "nested if" and "multi-way if" as mutually-exclusive (rather than just two possible permutations) blurs what's really going on, IMO...

Answer (score 3):

Say you've got two bowls.

In a multi-way 'if' statement, you only get to eat out of one of them.

```
 if ( choice.equals( "apples" )) {
     eatApples();
 }
 else if ( choice.equals( "oranges")) {
     eatOranges();
 }
```

In a nested 'if' statement, the bowls are nested together. You might eat the chips out of the outer one, and *maybe* dip them into the salsa in the middle.

```
if ( choice.equals( "chips" )) {
   getChip();
   if ( dip.equals( "salsa")) {
      dipChipInSalsa();
   }
}
```

Comment: @andybfmv96 - You're welcome. And welcome to stackoverflow. Don't hestitate to ask additional questions. Be sure to take the tour at http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**

At the language level, there's no fundamental difference.  What some people might call "nested if" and "multi-way if" are really just two particular configurations of nested `if`/`else` blocks.  They're certainly not the only options, let alone mutually-exclusive.

**Detail**

In general, conditions can be nested arbitrarily deeply:

```
if (a) {
    stuff();
    if (b) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
} else {
    moreStuff();
    if (c) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

What we call "nested if" is really just this:

```
if (a) {
    // Blank!
    if (b) {
        ...
    } else {
        // Blank!
    }
} else {
    // Blank!
}
```

and "multi-way if" is really just this:

```
if (a) {
    ...
} else {
    // Blank!
    if (b) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

(Note: there is no `else if` construct in C.)

Comment: While I think this is technically correct, I think it's probably more useful for new programmers to treat the two kinds of `if` statements as different.  Otherwise a newer programmer is likely to get the structure all wrong.  So I think Andy's answer is the correct one until they start learning compiler construction, and then yours is correct :) :)

Comment: @ajb: I somewhat agree ;)  However, I don't think compiler construction is the prerequisite; it's important that new programmers understand that "else if" isn't magic, and that they should be writing the logic that makes sense, rather than shoehorning it into two models.